# Method Range of _Global object failed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I get a Method Range of Object _Global failed error due to the following code

SOMETIMES this code works SOMETIMES it doesnt. I understand the cause of it but not how to fix it. How do i specify which sheet this is selecting everytime so that it works consistently.

```
'Fill Formulas'

Range(columnLetter & "5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(columnLetter & "5:" & columnLetter & "113"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range(columnLetter & "143").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(columnLetter & "143:" & columnLetter & "251"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Here is all of my code

```
Public Sub AutoUpdateCancels()

    Dim MySheetPath As String
    Dim Xl As Excel.Application
    Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim formattedDate As String
    Dim lngRow As Long, intCol As Integer, db As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, fld As DAO.Field
    Dim columnLetter As String
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    columnLetter = DLookup("[Column]", "[tblColumnIdentifier17]", "[WED] like #" & [Forms]![frmCancelsReporting]![txtCancelsWED] & "#")
    formattedDate = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    MySheetPath = "M:\Chris\Weekly Pulse\Cancel Report\2018\COM\Cancels Report - 2018v2.xlsx"

'Open Excel and the workbook and save a backup
    Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set XlBook = Xl.Workbooks.Open(MySheetPath, True)
    Xl.Visible = True
    XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(11)
    'Xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="M:\Chris\Weekly Pulse\Cancel Report\Backups\COM Backup 03-12-2018.xlsx"

'Clear Detail'
    Xl.Range("A256:D371").Select
    Xl.Selection.ClearContents


'Starting Row Number'
    lngRow = 256
'Append New Detail'
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryCancelsReport")
    qdf.Parameters("EndDate").Value = [Forms]![frmCancelsReporting]![txtCancelsWED]
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset()
    Xl.Cells(lngRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst


'Fill Formulas'

    Range(columnLetter & "5").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(columnLetter & "5:" & columnLetter & "113"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Range(columnLetter & "143").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(columnLetter & "143:" & columnLetter & "251"), Type:=xlFillDefault



    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set Xl = Nothing
    Set XlBook = Nothing
    Set XlSheet = Nothing
MsgBox ("Make sure to save over original worksheet not as backup")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You were not referencing proper objects (e.g.:  you used Xl.Range() instead of xlSheet.Range())

Avoid using Select/Selection/Activate/ActiveXXX coding pattern an use fully qualified range references (e.g. use xlSheet.Range() instead of Range())

So try this snippet:

```
With XlBook.Worksheets(11) ‘reference wanted sheet. From now on and till next ‘End With’ all referenced sheet members (like its Range()) are just a dot (.) away:

    'Clear Detail'
    .Range("A256:D371").ClearContents

    'Starting Row Number'
    lngRow = 256

    'Append New  
    ....

    .Cells(lngRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst

    'Fill Formulas'

    .Range(columnLetter & "5").AutoFill Destination:=.Range(columnLetter & "5:" & columnLetter & "113"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    .Range(columnLetter & "143").AutoFill Destination:=.Range(columnLetter & "143:" & columnLetter & "251"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End With
```

Comment: This did not affect any of my cells including the .Copyfromrecordset - There are many 13 tabs could this have an effect?

Comment: It should be noted in my original code, when i get the error, if i hit end, close the workbook without saving, and then run the module again, it somehow magically works..... But then the very next attempt I get the same error

Comment: I only corrected the excel range references. Cannot check if your recordset code is ok

Comment: My recordset code is okay, it currently works with my above code

Comment: @TylerJames, look, I have no clues about how your data looks and gets extracted. But you can step through the code and use Immediate Window to query relevant variables and see what's actually heppening

Comment: Okay well you dont need to get defensive. I am telling you that my code works more than what you suggested, I am not saying youre wrong I am saying it doesnt work for me any more than my solution does. I know basic debugging steps thats why I am here asking because I am coming across an error that makes no sense. Your code gives me no error but does not auto fill the destination nor does it copy from record set.

Comment: Also, the data could be anything it doesnt matter what it is. It gets extracted using the CopyFromRecordset method which works.

Comment: I’m not getting defensive. Just cannot follow you further than correcting the range references. While I do suggest you to step through your code (place mouse cursor anywhere inside the code to run and press F8 to start it, then press F8 to step through subsequent statements to be executed) and query relevant variables in Immediate Window (Ctrl-G to pop it out) where you could type any command (for instance: ?columLetter) and press return to see the outcome

Comment: Thank you for explaining how to use the debug windows I actually never could figure out how to step through in vba like I could in javascript and c#

Comment: you are welcome. so did you succeed in catching the thief?